# How to properly change focus item in the ListView control?

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi, mfc

If I want to change the focus item in the ListView control I do the following:

```
BOOL setListFocusItem(CListCtrl* pList, int nIndex)
{
    return !!pList->SetItemState(nInd, LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_FOCUSED);
}
```

Is this the way you do it?

Because the focus itself changes but there's one issue that this creates. For instance, if the list had 100 items and the focus was on item 1. If I then call my method as such `setListFocusItem(99);` the focus changes to item 99, but then if I shift-click on item 90, I would expect the list to have items 90 through 99 to be selected. But instead the list selects items 1 through 90. So obviously my `setListFocusItem()` method does not change the shift-click "first" location. So question is how to make it do it?

Comment: Just as an aside, this is standard behavior for the listview. If you click on file A, then with the control key held cursor down to move the focus (but not selection) to file D, and then shift-click on file H, the range goes from A->H, not D->H.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce it. Can you explain it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer : use the [`LVM_SETSELECTIONMARK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761204(v=vs.85).aspx) message.

(In MFC-ese, [`CListCtrl::SetSelectionMark`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck58ex74(v=vs.90).aspx)).

Comment: And you will probably want to enable the `LVIS_SELECTED` item state as well, not just `LVIS_FOCUSED`.  An item can be focused but not selected, and vice versa.  That is why they are separate state flags.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thank you. I did not know that it was called "selection mark."

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Not necessarily. This is not about item selection. For instance, my list may have 1, 2, ten thousand, or 0 selected items. All that has nothing to do with the item focus. Adding `CListCtrl::SetSelectionMark` to my code above fixes the issue with the shift-click that I described in my original post.